# How to add EmailComposer plugin to IOS phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I would like to send textField data to gmail in PhoneGap.I have done this in android and working well.When it comes to ios i am facing problem.
What i did is

```
i have added MessageUI.Freamework to my project.
i have added APPEmailcomposer.h and APPEmailcomposer.m in plugin floder.
i have added EmailComposert.js into asset/www/js floder.
```

I followed these steps to call EmailComposer in ios. But I didn't get an output. So please guide me in correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Because simply you need to define an email account on Iphone